# Unity character walking with no input

Tags: unity-game-engine

Problem; my player acts like im always holding the 'w' key

So I have tried using first person all in one as well as easy fps player controllers. I have double checked the input system using the input system manager and visualizers, have unplugged every usb device aside from my keyboard and mouse and found no inputs out of the ordinary being detected. Even with no usb devices plugged in the player walks.

So, multiple player prefabs in multiple project files, both urp and 3d, will act like a forward walk input is detected even if i have unplugged every usb device. Im at a loss

Comment: Did you try running it on some other device? Mobile phone or other pc.
Also sharing your code snippets  will attract more people to actually help you.

Comment: wish i had another pc to test it on, was meant to accept touch input so i cant use my phone.
if i had code to share i would have, was onlyl trying to get two common player prefabs to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have not set the velocity as always increasing. Make it increase only when the “w” key is pressed. Here is the code that I use for my player movement -

```
//Input
float x, y;
bool jumping, sprinting, crouching;

//Movement
public float moveSpeed = 4500;
public float maxSpeed = 20;


private void Update()
{
    MyInput();
}

private void MyInput()
{
    x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
}

private void Movement()
{
    //Extra gravity
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);

    Vector2 mag = FindVelRelativeToLook();
    float xMag = mag.x, yMag = mag.y;

    CounterMovement(x, y, mag);

    //Set max speed
    float maxSpeed = this.maxSpeed;

    //If speed is larger than maxspeed, cancel out the input so you don't go over max speed
    if (x > 0 && xMag > maxSpeed) x = 0;
    if (x < 0 && xMag < -maxSpeed) x = 0;
    if (y > 0 && yMag > maxSpeed) y = 0;
    if (y < 0 && yMag < -maxSpeed) y = 0;

    //Some multipliers
    float multiplier = 1f, multiplierV = 1f;

    // Movement in air
    if (!grounded)
    {
        multiplier = 0.3f;
        multiplierV = 0.3f;
    }

    //Apply forces to move player
    rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * y * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier * multiplierV);
    rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.right * x * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier);
}
```

Hope so this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you, this code does seem to work fine. dont know whats wrong with the two prefabs i was trying (easyfps and first personal all in one) but this code and the starter assets First Person Character Controller both work flawlessly

Comment: If this helped you, can you mark it as accepted answer